Vue.js 3 Composition API cannot pass router parameters
Get parameters from vue-router 4 with composision API vue.js 3 doesnt seem to work, its was easy on vue.js 2 before,
anyhow heres my code
    import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
    import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

    setup () {
    
      const router = useRouter();
    
       onMounted(async() => {
         try {
           const routerready = await router.isReady();
// => if i add router ready check, it will produce black in console.log
// => if i dont, then produce typeError
           if (routerready) {
            const pid = router.params.uid;
            console.log(pid);
           }
         } catch (error) {
           console.log(error);
         }
        })
    }

and its produce 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uid')' Hope someone helps :(


i was even try to implement props with defineProps like https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props its still not working

Can you post your router config?

Did you try router.currentRoute.value.params.uid? I think that's the syntax you want

its SOLVED by adding const route = useRoute() besides const router = useRouter(), and use it to call Parameter ID, i dont know that vue-reouter need two diferent definition, Thanks for comment guys, i hope this queston will help other :)
